# SQL query to get rows with maximum of some column

Tags: sql

I have a VehicleData table. Need to write SQL query to get row with maximum speed of every vehicle. That is I need a result set with 5 rows (say 5 distinct vehicles) each row is corresponding to maximum speed of respective vehicle. I know its simple, but I couldn't get it somehow

Comment: . . When you post a question, you should show the structure of the tables you are working with, sample input data, the results you want, and your attempts at writing a query.  In addition, you should tag the question appropriately, with the database and a homework tag if this is for homework.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: apparently they're getting rid of the homework tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag

Comment: So `homework` is obsolete. That explains a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the following syntax which uses the [max](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp) function:

```
select vehicleID, max(vehicleSpeed) from vehicleData group by vehicleID
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your table structure, you will use the `MAX()` aggregate function and a `GROUP BY` clause to be sure you get one record for each vehicle:

```
SELECT vehicleName, Max(speed)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY vehicleName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select vehicle, max(speed)
from table
group by vehicle
```